# Dynamically create entities, Spring repositories and facelets pages in Java or Grails application

Tags: java, grails, jpa, orm, metaprogramming

I have requirements to let users create their own tables and to create their own forms dynamically inside application. One can image that there can be 3 separate tables: user_relations, user_relation_fields, user_relation_field_values. Together they can satisfy requirements. But apparently such solution is involved, each select requires lot of joins. It is easy to create tables dynamically and it is easy to create CRUD SQL statements dynamically from the set of fields which have been defined by users. I prefer to use annotations (instead of configruation XML files), therefor dynamic update of configuration files may not be necessary.

The question is - how to create ORM (JPA, Spring Repository) mapping to dynamically created tables. Is it possible dynamically create entities and insert them as part of already running application? Is it possible to dynamically create code of facelets pages and insert then in application? Is it good practice.

Lot of ERP type applications allow some kind of flexfields or extensibility features so this should be possible.

I have heard that Grails is dynamic Java with metaprogramming features maybe it is more appropriate to create such application in Grails (especially because it uses Spring and Hibernate)?

Any hints or suggestions are welcome. I guess it should be possible to do but some initial ideas would be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: I am investigating idea about using OSGi bundles - each new set of tables can be OSGi bundle that inherts some base clases and templates and maybe it is possible to create OSGi bundles dynamically at runtime and install them in the main application?

Comment: Maybe this is good idea, unfortunately there is already patent about it "OSGi dynamic bundle generation at runtime" US 8230389 B2

Answer (score 0):

I wondering why people need all this schemas, design patterns and so on. Sometimes it is better to write something from lower level. Your task is very good case. In my opinion it's better to write this module in pure jdbc/hql without mappings. It is worth to think about database type. It is not easy to implement dynamic entities in relation based database. Maybe NoSQL database will be better choice.